# How to change the template path dynamically in Django 1.8

Tags: django

I want to add the mobile version to my site, so I need to change the template path dynamically to get the mobile template dir or the desktop dir.

As the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is deprecated since version 1.8, I tried to change the `DIRS` option of a `DjangoTemplates` backend, but it didn't work.

Comment: what happens after you change the DIRS? Is there any error?

Comment: You probably need a custom template loader to do this. Have a look at how [django_mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/django_mobile/loader.py) does it.

Comment: You should not be changing settings dynamically. That can lead to all sorts of unpredictable thread-safety issues.

Comment: What sort of changes do you need to make? If a parent layout is enough, you can do something like `{% extends request.is_mobile|yesno:'mobile.html,layout.html' %}`.

Comment: @MaximHaytovich,i set up a middleware to change the DIRS, but the template path didn't change, django still loaded the template in the dir set in the settings.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,u are right, a custom template loader may be my better choice,thanks.

Comment: @solarissmoke,it is a nice solution to my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same challenge I post my code here. I am using the get_flavor from [django_mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) to detect what to show and I wanted to use the standard admin directories (as installed) for [django_admin_bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) and the regular django admin. In addition I wanted to only interfere the loader with admin pages and not with regular pages - in the latter case the loader does nothing.

So this works for me:

```
import os.path

from django.template.loaders.base import Loader 
from django.template.loader import LoaderOrigin
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist

from django_mobile import get_flavour

class Myloader(Loader):
    is_usable = True #this line is necessary to make it work

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
         path_split = template_name.split("/")
         if not u'admin' in path_split:
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist
        template_short_name = path_split[-1]

        if get_flavour() == "mobile":
            basepath = r'/path/to/django_admin_bootstrapped/templates/admin'
            path = os.path.join(basepath,template_short_name)
        else:
            basepath = r'/path/to/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin'
            path = os.path.join(basepath,template_short_name)
        try:
            with open(path,"r") as f1:
                template_string = f1.read()
        except IOError:
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist

        template_origin = LoaderOrigin(template_short_name, self.load_template_source, template_name, template_dirs)

        return (template_string, template_origin)
```

If you want to distinguish the template path by something different e.g. by the name in the url you need to replace the "if get_flavour()=="mobile" " by looking for something inntemplate_name.